# XNA resolution independence

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xna, resolution

For some reason, everything I tried that was online about resolution independence doesn't really work the way I would want it to. Most of the solutions suggest a way to get the width and height and then use a class with them, but the result is always a cutoff picture(too big picture) or a picture in the top left corner with smaller height and width than those of the screen.

P.S. The game is in fullscreen, but we tried windowed and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a pretty simple fix. Basically, create a `RenderTarget` object somewhere and do all your drawing to that object, then resize that to the screen.

Use `GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(target)` to change the render target, then do all your drawing operations, then change it back to the back buffer afterwards by setting it to `null`. RenderTargets actually derive from `Texture2D`, so you can use it in as an argument, such as: `SpriteBatch.Draw(renderTarget, Viewport.Bounds, Color.White)`, and this will stretch it to fit the screen.

Comment: We already have a pretty big project, does this mean we have to change all of the draws. I am sorry, but I do not fully understand what "so you can use it in as an argument, such as: SpriteBatch.Draw(renderTarget, Viewport.Bounds, Color.White)" means . I am not sure how to draw everything with the render target.

Comment: At the beginning of your `Game.Draw()` method, add `GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(target)` before the `GraphicsDevice.Clear()`. Then do all your normal draw calls, and then call `GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null)`. "target" is an object of type `RenderTarget2D`. At this point, you should have nothing drawn but a purple background - this means nothing has been drawn to the screen or backbuffer, but rather, the target you provided! Now, you call `SpriteBatch.Draw()`, and where any of the overloads ask for a `Texture2D` object, you can provide it the "target".

Comment: But doesn't it need the Texture2D to know what texture to draw?

Comment: Because the `RenderTarget2D` is a class which derives from `Texture2D`, you can use the render target in place of a texture, once it has been drawn to.